# How should I terminate a flooring transition where it meets door casing?

Tags: hardwood

I’m refinishing my hardwood floors(they were covered with carpet) and I have a height difference going from the dining room to the engineered wood floor in the kitchen of about 3/4”.

I found the perfect reducer transition piece but I'm not sure how to end it on the sides because it goes right into the door trim. I'm trying to figure out the least abrupt way to end the piece so it flows better.

I was thinking about sawing out the bottom of the door trim so the reducer sits under the door trim.

Any suggestions would be great. Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since the transition sticks beyond the trim you'll also want to think about the shape of the ends of the transition that stick into the room beyond the trim. Some sort of angle or curve back to meet the wall is more finished looking than just sticking out at 90 degrees there. A roundover of the side edge after cutting the shape you choose may also help.

For the instersection with the door trim:

- You can cut off the door trim and slide under, though it appears that
  you might end up with a somewhat large gap because the transition
  tapers, so if the door trim cut clears the back of the transition the
  front of the door trim may be well above the installed edge of the
  transition.
- The other option is to use a pin gauge to copy the shape of the door
  trim onto the ends of the transition and cut it to fit against the
  door trim with a coping saw.

Comment: I think undercutting the door trim to match the transition's rounded taper would be harder than simply coping the transition.  As to the "problem" of the transition being longer than the width of the threshold, one option is the "return" to meet the baseboard you mention, but another option could be to simply cut back the threshold piece so that the low edge of the transition is even with the door jamb in this room.  (Also, what's up with the threshold—is it made of multiple crosswise strips of wood with a veneer on top?)

Comment: If you undercut it to match the rounded taper, the transition won't fit in. The threshold is presumably of "engineered" wood, so yes, veneer over whatever.

Comment: If you simply undercut then, you're using a lot of caulk—or you cut out a chunk, round-taper the bottom cut, and reinstall with some caulk/filler after the transition is in place.

Comment: Thus my first point regarding a somewhat large gap.

Comment: Alternative to pin gauge is scribing to fit, of course. Or whittling it into place, though that of course is slower.

Comment: Yeah you’re right about the big gap if I undercut it because of the transition taper. I might try scribing the transition piece like you’ve said and rounding the corner of the piece. Seems like the best option.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need to cover a gap at the casing, you could just do a miter return fit to the inside of the opening jamb. This would create a nice rounded end profile (as opposed to a hard, square edge).

To do this, cut back at a 45° angle from the front (thin edge) long point, and cut an opposing angle for the return.

```
PLAN (TOP) VIEW

      jamb   |  high floor
             |__________________________________________________
   casing   ||  /
 ___________|| /  transition
             |/________________________
        
               low floor
```

Here's the best image I could find. It's not your exact scenario, so I've added some expert graphical elements to illustrate.

[image]